# How can I prevent the width changing when using jQuery's slideUp?

Tags: jquery, css, slideup

I have a test-case here:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/kPBbb/

Once the content has `.content`, the `.wrapper` shrink-wraps itself, presumably because the `.content` is `display: none`ed. I would like the `.wrapper` to behave as if the `.content` were still there after the animation, maintaing the initial size.

The `.wrapper` has been `float: left`ed in order to show the issue (by forcing shrink-wrap behavior), but may not always be, so I'd like a solution that *doesn't* involve reading the width of the box before the animation, and reapplying it after.

Is there a simple fix?

Answer (score 1):

Or to make it dynamic try the following:

```
var contentWidth = $('.content').width();

$('.header').width(contentWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the width of the wrapper, it will stay the same size if you slide toggle a child of it.

```
.wrapper{
    width: 200px;
}
```

I am not sure if there is a better/more generic solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using display:none you can use `visibility:hidden` and then `visibility:visible` to display the information.

```
display:none
```

This will act as if the data is not on the page and this is why the wrapper will shrink itself once the display property is changed to `none`

```
visibility:hidden
```

Visibility allows the data to still be stored in its place on the page but is merely invisible.

Try this out and see if this helps you with your question.

Comment: jQuery adds the `display: none` as part of the animation process. That's out of my control.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do this:

```
$('.wrapper').each(function() {
  var wrapper = this;
  $('.header', wrapper).click(function() {
    $(this).css('width',$(this).width());
    $('.content', wrapper).slideToggle();
  });
});​
```

But maybe you can even do this:

```
$('.wrapper').each(function() {
    var wrapper = this;
    $('.header', wrapper).click(function() {
        $('.content', wrapper).slideToggle('slow',function(){
            $('.content', wrapper).show();
            $('.content', wrapper).css('visibility','hidden');
            $('.content', wrapper).css('height','0px');
        });
    });
});
```

​